# ANgular2- Display validation message only when user leaves out the fields

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am using formGroup for form validation in angular2.I am doing a validation for Phone Number.I want the validation message to be displayed only when user leaves the field/tabs out.Right now, the validations are working fine but the validation message appears even when I am focused to the field.
For ex.- If I try to change the phone number and make the digits equal to 10 , it throws error(though I have not tabbed out).I want the error to be displayed only when I tab out. Any idea what am i missing here.

```
<form [formGroup]="paymentDetailsForm">
    <md-input formControlName="officePhone" placeholder="Primary Contact Phone" name="officePhone" [(ngModel)]="paymentform.officePhone" (blur)="registerChaseUser()" (keyup)="numberKeyed($event.target.value)" [restrictKey]="'^[0-9]+$'" noSpace="true" maxlength="14" required></md-input>
         <span *ngIf="!paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].valid && (!paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].pristine || paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].touched || showPaymentError) && paymentform.officePhone.length == 0" class="validation validation-fix">This field is required.</span>
         <span *ngIf="(paymentform.officePhone.length < 14) && (paymentform.officePhone.length > 0) && (!paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].pristine || paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].touched)" class="validation validation-fix">Please enter a full 10-digit phone number.</span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you check for touched?

Comment: It is working fine but it throws error even when I try to change the number.

Answer (score 1):

Try using blur

```
<input (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()">
```

and then activate the message only if onblur was called.

Comment: Hi, you shoud try 'ngTouch'

Answer (score 0):

you should try 'ngTouch'

```
instead of "|| paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].touched"
should write "&& paymentDetailsForm.controls['officePhone'].touched"
```

for example :

```
            <form *ngIf="active" id="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onContactSubmit()" [formGroup]="contactForm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <label for="first-name"> First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
                        <p *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.firstName.valid&&contactForm.controls.firstName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
                            firstname is required
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <label for="last-name"> Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="lastName">
                        <p *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.lastName.valid&&contactForm.controls.lastName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">lastname is required</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```